# Discrepancy between “last seen” and “newest” post

Tags: support, profile-page

I don't know if this is a bug. It could be, or there might be a simple explanation.

I was visiting a user's profile because they had become uncharacteristically quiet when I noticed the following. The user's last visit is recorded as being March 17

> [image]

However, when I visited their answer page I saw the following

> [image]

Is there an explanation for this (seemingly) odd behaviour? How is it possible to post an answer seven days later without that visit being recorded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/202140/18673) was migrated from English Language & Usage to English Language Learners. The user posted the answer on EL&U on March 24th, so they were active *there*, but not on the target site, where you were looking at the profile.

Comment: Blimey, how did you know who the user was? I thought I kept it rather anonymous.

Comment: By running [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1021014) on the sites you're active on :)

Comment: I should have visited the answer posted, then I might have added 1+1

Comment: Well, it was a nice little puzzle. And it *is* an unusual situation...